# Coordinate system identification

Tags: gdal, coordinate-system, coordinates

I have two DEMs I want to combine into a single 3D model.  Model 1 fits within Model 2 geographically, but they use different coordinate systems, as shown below.  How can I identify the coordinate systems & provide the right gdalwarp command so that they import (via BlenderGIS) in the same location and at the same scale?

**Model 1:**

```
Coordinate System is:
PROJCS["WGS_1984_UTM_Zone_10N",
    GEOGCS["WGS 84",
        DATUM["WGS_1984",
            SPHEROID["WGS 84",6378137,298.257223563,
                AUTHORITY["EPSG","7030"]],
            AUTHORITY["EPSG","6326"]],
        PRIMEM["Greenwich",0],
        UNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433],
        AUTHORITY["EPSG","4326"]],
    PROJECTION["Transverse_Mercator"],
    PARAMETER["latitude_of_origin",0],
    PARAMETER["central_meridian",-123],
    PARAMETER["scale_factor",0.9996],
    PARAMETER["false_easting",500000],
    PARAMETER["false_northing",0],
    UNIT["metre",1,
        AUTHORITY["EPSG","9001"]],
    AUTHORITY["EPSG","32610"]]
Origin = (533699.999999790801667,4190050.000110663473606)
Pixel Size = (2.000000000000000,-2.000000000000000)
Metadata:
  AREA_OR_POINT=Area
  DataType=Generic
Image Structure Metadata:
  INTERLEAVE=BAND
Corner Coordinates:
Upper Left  (  533700.000, 4190050.000) (122d37' 0.85"W, 37d51'26.23"N)
Lower Left  (  533700.000, 4172360.000) (122d37' 3.81"W, 37d41'52.25"N)
Upper Right (  551400.000, 4190050.000) (122d24'56.52"W, 37d51'23.26"N)
Lower Right (  551400.000, 4172360.000) (122d25' 1.03"W, 37d41'49.29"N)
Center      (  542550.000, 4181205.000) (122d31' 0.55"W, 37d46'37.91"N)
Band 1 Block=128x128 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Gray
  NoData Value=255
```

**Model 2:**

```
Coordinate System is `'
Origin = (-124.000138888890007,38.750138902890001)
Pixel Size = (0.000277777780000,-0.000277777780000)
Image Structure Metadata:
  INTERLEAVE=BAND
Corner Coordinates:
Upper Left  (-124.0001389,  38.7501389) 
Lower Left  (-124.0001389,  36.9998611) 
Upper Right (-121.8498611,  38.7501389) 
Lower Right (-121.8498611,  36.9998611) 
Center      (-122.9250000,  37.8750000) 
Band 1 Block=7741x1 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Gray
  NoData Value=0
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Model 2 is in the most obvious coordinate system: [EPSG:4326 (WGS84)](http://epsg.io/4326)

```
gdalwarp -s_srs EPSG:4326 -t_srs EPSG:32610 srcfile dstfile
```

Comment: Can you please elaborate as to why you think it's obviously EPSG:4326?

Comment: Brilliant!  That worked!  Could you explain how you knew it was that coordinate system?

Comment: @ed94133 When you see values <+/-180 (or possibly 360), the data is almost certainly using a geographic coordinate reference system which has units of decimal degrees. A projected CRS using meters or feet will have values that are usually minimum 10k up through 20 million.

Comment: @ed94133 First choice is usually WGS84 (EPSG:4326) as it's very common. If data is offset by a few meters to a few hundred meters, the geoCRS could be something else.